# Counting a Loop

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

I have this huge animation loop that controls the program for a video game. I have this if statement that that gets executed several times because as soon as it's true it keeps on getting executed because of the loop. I need this statement to only get executed once. I know one way to solve it is by making an integer variable as a counter, but I was wondering if there are any other ways to solve this.

Comment: Please provide some example code.

Comment: @Tim it looks like he doesn't want to break out of the loop, just execute the contents of the `if` when its conditions become true, then continue with the loop afterwards. EDIT: But yeah, it sounds like you're probably approaching this from the wrong angle, and if you post some code we can help you to improve it.

Comment: @Tharwen Ah I see.  Okay the question makes (a bit) more sense now.

Answer (score 3):

You say as soon as *it* is *true*, it continues to get executed. When you don't want this `if` statement to get executed anymore, make *it* `false`, and if you can't do that, then set some kind of `boolean` flag.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [continue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html). In pseudocode

```
set flag = false
for(var1 == var2)
  ...//do whatever you do in loop
  if(flag)
    continue
  if(var3 == var4)
    set flag = true
  ...//do whatever in if statment
end for loop
```

alternatively

```
set flag = false
for(var1 == var2)
  ...//do whatever you do in loop
  if(var3 == var4 AND !flag)
    set flag = true
  ...//do whatever in if statment
end for loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this because its an expensive if statement? You can try adding short circuiting logic:

```
for(...)
{
     if(flag == false && ...)
     {
          flag = true;
     }
}
```

If your concerned about the performance of doing the compare ... you can separate this into two loops. One for when the condition is false and the second for when the condition is true.

I'd imagine that some compiler optimizations may already take care of this problem though.

Answer (score 0):

make that if statement check the specific number like

```
for(i=0;i<10000;i++) {
    if(i==345) {
        // do something...
    }
}
```